# PyDev Offline install

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pydev

I have a windows machine which has no connection to the internet. It's also not possible to connect this machine to the internet due security reasons.

How can I install `PyDev` without internet connection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) use [SourceForge download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/) and install manually via these instructions:

```
Installing with the zip file

The available locations for the zip files are:

Sourceforge download
After downloading the zip file:

Eclipse 3.4 onwards

Extract the contents of the zip file in the eclipse/dropins folder and restart Eclipse.

Before Eclipse 3.4

Extract the contents of the zip file on top of Eclipse, making sure the plugins folder     is extracted on top of the 
eclipse/plugins folder and the features is on top of the eclipse/features folder.
After that, restart Eclipse with the '-clean' flag, so that Eclipse finds out about it.
```

Answer (score 1):

use http://www.liclipse.com.  It has PyDev builtin and easy to install.

Comment: It might be worth noting, that LiClipse is a commercial product, which might be problem for people looking for free SW ("In short terms, the license alows anyone to evaluate LiClipse for 30 days, but it must be bought for continued use.
")